# Linkedin API for median tenure

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, linkedin-api

The aim is to use the API to request the median tenure for a companies in a list.
If there is no official way then would be bootstrapped way be using selenium and searching each name, clicking the profile and reverting to the insights tab, is this possible with selenium?